# Flutter dynamic data from api to make Widgets

Tags: json, flutter, api

In my case the json will be different every time and i have to make widget like "inputtype": "dropdown", "inputtype": "radiobutton"  but if i craete model it don't go as i wants it to.

```
{
```

"fields": [
{
"id": 31,
"name": "make",
"isrequired": "required",
"valuetype": "text",
"priority": 1,
"inputtype": "dropdown",
"max_min": [],
"rangeable": "false",
"choices": [
{
"id": 46,
"name": "Samsung",
"categoryextrafield_id": 31,
"created_at": "2021-12-29T01:30:47.000000Z",
"updated_at": "2021-12-29T01:30:47.000000Z",
"priority": 10
},
{
"id": 47,
"name": "Dell",
"categoryextrafield_id": 31,
"created_at": "2021-12-29T01:30:52.000000Z",
"updated_at": "2021-12-29T01:30:52.000000Z",
"priority": 20
},
{
"id": 48,
"name": "IBM",
"categoryextrafield_id": 31,
"created_at": "2021-12-29T01:31:09.000000Z",
"updated_at": "2021-12-29T01:31:09.000000Z",
"priority": 30
},
{
"id": 49,
"name": "Acer",
"categoryextrafield_id": 31,
"created_at": "2021-12-29T01:31:24.000000Z",
"updated_at": "2021-12-29T01:31:24.000000Z",
"priority": 40
}
],
"available": []
},
{
"id": 32,
"name": "model",
"isrequired": "required",
"valuetype": "text",
"priority": 2,
"inputtype": "textfield",
"max_min": [],
"rangeable": "false",
"choices": [],
"available": [
{
"model": "a51"
},
{
"model": "y9s"
},
{
"model": "a31"
},
{
"model": "yS10"
},
{
"model": "Y10S"
},
{
"model": "A551"
},
{
"model": "node8"
},
{
"model": "s9"
},
{
"model": null
},
{
"model": "2021"
},
{
"model": "2020"
},
{
"model": "2010"
},
{
"model": "Civic"
},
{
"model": "2019"
},
{
"model": "Daewooy9"
},
{
"model": "corei5"
},
{
"model": "corei9"
},
{
"model": "corei3"
},
{
"model": "corei11"
}
]
},
{
"id": 29,
"name": "features",
"isrequired": "required",
"valuetype": "text",
"priority": 3,
"inputtype": "checkbox",
"max_min": [],
"rangeable": "false",
"choices": [
{
"id": 41,
"name": "Bluetooth",
"categoryextrafield_id": 29,
"created_at": "2021-12-29T01:19:00.000000Z",
"updated_at": "2021-12-29T01:19:00.000000Z",
"priority": 1
},
{
"id": 42,
"name": "Fingerprint",
"categoryextrafield_id": 29,
"created_at": "2021-12-29T01:19:10.000000Z",
"updated_at": "2021-12-29T01:19:10.000000Z",
"priority": 10
},
{
"id": 43,
"name": "LedDisplay",
"categoryextrafield_id": 29,
"created_at": "2021-12-29T01:19:35.000000Z",
"updated_at": "2021-12-29T01:19:35.000000Z",
"priority": 15
}
],
"available": []
},
{
"id": 30,
"name": "condition",
"isrequired": "required",
"valuetype": "text",
"priority": 4,
"inputtype": "radiobutton",
"max_min": [],
"rangeable": "false",
"choices": [
{
"id": 44,
"name": "Used",
"categoryextrafield_id": 30,
"created_at": "2021-12-29T01:20:31.000000Z",
"updated_at": "2021-12-29T01:20:31.000000Z",
"priority": 10
},
{
"id": 45,
"name": "New",
"categoryextrafield_id": 30,
"created_at": "2021-12-29T01:20:38.000000Z",
"updated_at": "2021-12-29T01:20:38.000000Z",
"priority": 20
}
],
"available": []
}
]
}

Comment: This is what i did but it's not gonna work if json data changes

companyList = data['fields'][0]['choices'];
        if (companyList.length != 0) {
          int val;
          for (val = 0; val < companyList.length; val++) {
            final controller = TextEditingController();
            final field = xTextfield(
              txtlabel: "Values",
              iconfield: bookmarksIcon,
            );

            setState(() {
              _controllers.add(controller);
              _fields.add(field);
            });
          }
        }

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.